# Как забрать каждый элемент таблицы отдельно в bs4

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4, таблицы

у меня есть проблема с парсингом с помощью bs4, у меня задача спарсить сайт и вывести таблицу примерно такого образца: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблицу построить я то смогу, только на сайте эти данные указаны в качестве таблицы, и мне их нужно разложить каждый элемент по отдельным переменным, что бы сформировать корректно таблицу, но я не могу понять как мне достать каждый элемент отдельно, что бы потом взаимодействовать с ним, это было бы просто сделать через xpath, но bs4 его не поддерживает, вот HTML код таблицы которую мне нужно вытянуть:

```html
<div class="product-tabs-grid"><div class="product-tabs-grid__main"><div class="product-specifications"><div class="product-specifications-title">Основные</div> <table class="product-specifications-table"><tbody><tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value">
                                                                                                                                            Бренд&nbsp;
                                                                                                                                        
                                                                </div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        70mai                                                                                                                                                                                                    </b></td></tr> <tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value">
                                                                                                                                            Конструкция&nbsp;
                                                                                                                                        
                                                                </div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        С камерой и экраном                                                                                                                                                                                                    </b></td></tr> <tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value"><span>Режим записи&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="product-specifications-table__info tooltip ic-info tooltipstered"></a></span></div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        Циклическая                                                                                                                                                                                                    </b></td></tr> <tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value"><span>GPS&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="product-specifications-table__info tooltip ic-info tooltipstered"></a></span></div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        Нет                                                                                                                            </b></td></tr> <tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value">
                                                                                                                                            ГЛОНАСС&nbsp;
                                                                                                                                        
                                                                </div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        Нет                                                                                                                            </b></td></tr> <tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value"><span>Датчик движения (G-сенсор)&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="product-specifications-table__info tooltip ic-info tooltipstered"></a></span></div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        Да                                                                                                                             </b></td></tr> <tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value">
                                                                                                                                            Детектор движения в кадре&nbsp;
                                                                                                                                        
                                                                </div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        Да                                                                                                                             </b></td></tr> <tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value">
                                                                                                                                            Датчик звука&nbsp;
                                                                                                                                        
                                                                </div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        Нет                                                                                                                            </b></td></tr> <tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value">
                                                                                                                                            Радар-детектор&nbsp;
                                                                                                                                        
                                                                </div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        Нет                                                                                                                            </b></td></tr> <tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value">
                                                                                                                                            Встроенный микрофон&nbsp;
                                                                                                                                        
                                                                </div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        Да                                                                                                                             </b></td></tr> <tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value">
                                                                                                                                            Встроенный динамик&nbsp;
                                                                                                                                        
                                                                </div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        Да                                                                                                                             </b></td></tr> <tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value">
                                                                                                                                            Формат записи&nbsp;
                                                                                                                                        
                                                                </div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        H.264                                                                                                                                                                                                    </b></td></tr> <tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value">
                                                                                                                                            Крепление на присоске&nbsp;
                                                                                                                                        
                                                                </div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        Нет                                                                                                                            </b></td></tr> <tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value">
                                                                                                                                            Материал&nbsp;
                                                                                                                                        
                                                                </div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        Пластик                                                                                                                                                                                                    </b></td></tr> <tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value">
                                                                                                                                            Цвет&nbsp;
                                                                                                                                        
                                                                </div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        Черный                                                                                                                                                                                                    </b></td></tr> <tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value">
                                                                                                                                            Комплектация&nbsp;
                                                                                                                                        
                                                                </div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        Автомобильное зарядное устройство, Документация, Кабель USB                                                                                                                                                                                                    </b></td></tr> <tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value">
                                                                                                                                            Дополнительно&nbsp;
                                                                                                                                        
                                                                </div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        Wi-Fi                                                                                                                                                                                                    </b></td></tr></tbody></table> <div class="product-specifications-title">Память</div> <table class="product-specifications-table"><tbody><tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value"><span>Поддержка карт памяти&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="product-specifications-table__info tooltip ic-info tooltipstered"></a></span></div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        microSDHC, microSDXC, microSD                                                                                                                                                                                                    </b></td></tr> <tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value">
                                                                                                                                            Максимальный размер карты памяти&nbsp;
                                                                                                                                        
                                                                </div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        64                                                                        &nbsp;ГБ                                                                                                                            </b></td></tr> <tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value">
                                                                                                                                            Возможность установки жесткого диска&nbsp;
                                                                                                                                        
                                                                </div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        Нет                                                                                                                            </b></td></tr></tbody></table> <div class="product-specifications-title">Экран</div> <table class="product-specifications-table"><tbody><tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value">
                                                                                                                                            Экран&nbsp;
                                                                                                                                        
                                                                </div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        Да                                                                                                                             </b></td></tr> <tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value">
                                                                                                                                            Размер экрана&nbsp;
                                                                                                                                        
                                                                </div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        2                                                                        &nbsp;"                                                                                                                            </b></td></tr> <tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value"><span>Сенсорный экран&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="product-specifications-table__info tooltip ic-info tooltipstered"></a></span></div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        Нет                                                                                                                            </b></td></tr></tbody></table> <div class="product-specifications-title">Камера</div> <table class="product-specifications-table"><tbody><tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value">
                                                                                                                                            Тип матрицы&nbsp;
                                                                                                                                        
                                                                </div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        CMOS                                                                                                                                                                                                    </b></td></tr> <tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value"><span>Максимальное разрешение видеозаписи&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="product-specifications-table__info tooltip ic-info tooltipstered"></a></span></div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        1920x1080                                                                                                                                                                                                    </b></td></tr> <tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value"><span>Максимальная частота кадров&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="product-specifications-table__info tooltip ic-info tooltipstered"></a></span></div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        30                                                                        &nbsp;к/с                                                                                                                            </b></td></tr> <tr><td><div class="product-specifications-table__value"><span>Угол обзора&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="product-specifications-table__info tooltip ic-info tooltipstered"></a></span></div></td> <td><b>
                                                                                                                                        130                                                                        &nbsp;градусов
```

У меня есть код который может вывести то что мне нужно, но не в том формате в котором я хочу (Просто как массив элементов), помогите пожалуйста с моей задачей
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
def parse(url):
    items_list = []
    headers = {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A5341f Safari/604.1"}
    req = requests.get(url = "https://5element.by/products/641981-videoregistrator-70mai-dash-cam-lite-midrive-d08", headers=headers)
    src = req.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
    items = soup.find_all(class_="product-specifications-table")
    for item in items:
        tr_item = item.find_all("tr")
        for tr in tr_item:
            info = tr.find_all("td")
            name = info[1].getText()
            items_list.append(name)
            print(name.replace(" ", ''))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таблицы если что удобно через `Pandas` обрабатывать, хотя тут много повторов получается, а самой модели при этом нет. Но так, в дополнение к основным методам:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

headers = {
"Accept": "*/*",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A5341f Safari/604.1"}
req = requests.get(url = "https://5element.by/products/641981-videoregistrator-70mai-dash-cam-lite-midrive-d08", headers=headers)
df = pd.concat(pd.read_html(req.content))
df
```

В `df`:

| index | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Датчик движения (G-сенсор) | Да |
| 1 | Максимальное разрешение видеозаписи | 1920x1080 |
| 2 | Максимальная частота кадров | 30 к/с |
| 3 | Угол обзора | 130 градусов |
| 4 | Ночной режим | Да |
| 0 | Бренд | 70mai |
| 1 | Конструкция | С камерой и экраном |
| 2 | Режим записи | Циклическая |
| 3 | GPS | Нет |
| 4 | ГЛОНАСС | Нет |
| 5 | Датчик движения (G-сенсор) | Да |
| 6 | Детектор движения в кадре | Да |
| 7 | Датчик звука | Нет |
| 8 | Радар-детектор | Нет |
| 9 | Встроенный микрофон | Да |
| 10 | Встроенный динамик | Да |
| 11 | Формат записи | H.264 |
| 12 | Крепление на присоске | Нет |
| 13 | Материал | Пластик |
| 14 | Цвет | Черный |
| 15 | Комплектация | Автомобильное зарядное устройство, Документация, Кабель USB |
| 16 | Дополнительно | Wi-Fi |
| 0 | Поддержка карт памяти | microSDHC, microSDXC, microSD |
| 1 | Максимальный размер карты памяти | 64 ГБ |
| 2 | Возможность установки жесткого диска | Нет |
| 0 | Экран | Да |
| 1 | Размер экрана | 2 " |
| 2 | Сенсорный экран | Нет |
| 0 | Тип матрицы | CMOS |
| 1 | Максимальное разрешение видеозаписи | 1920x1080 |
| 2 | Максимальная частота кадров | 30 к/с |
| 3 | Угол обзора | 130 градусов |
| 4 | Ночной режим | Да |
| 5 | ИК-подсветка | Нет |
| 6 | Поворот камеры | Да |
| 0 | Количество каналов записи видео | 1 |
| 1 | Количество каналов записи звука | 1 |
| 2 | Выход HDMI | Нет |
| 3 | Подключение внешнего накопителя по USB | Нет |
| 0 | Питание | Автомобильный прикуриватель, Аккумулятор |
| 1 | Тип аккумулятора | Li-pol |
| 2 | Емкость аккумулятора | 500 мАч |
| 0 | Запись времени и даты | Да |
| 1 | Запись скорости | Нет |
| 2 | Автостарт записи | Да |
| 3 | Отключение микрофона | Да |
| 0 | Ширина | 58.2 мм |
| 1 | Высота | 82 мм |
| 2 | Толщина | 40.5 мм |
| 0 | Гарантия | 1 год |
| 1 | Срок службы | 1 год |
| 2 | Страна происхождения (производства) | Китай |

Comment: Спасибо за информацию!

Comment: А можно уточнить, могу ли я добавлять сюда свои строки? Например наименование товара или ссылку на него? И можно ли после каждой итерации добавлять сдвиг вправо, что бы справа добавлять следующий товар?

Comment: Да всё можно, но вам для этого нужно хоть немного разобраться с `Pandas`. Я очень рекомендую вам это сделать, для работы с табличными данными в питоне это самая удобная библиотека.

Comment: Добавлять и строки и столбцы можно через `pd.concat`, только для столбцов нужен параметр `axis=1`, но вам всё-равно нужно будет в целом с концепцией ознакомиться.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!